# D3D11CreateDevice with non-default adapter

Tags: windows-8, nvidia, directx-11, direct3d

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask ... please tell me if there are better places for this question.

When writing Direct3d 11 programs, I observed the following problem:

I have two GPUs on my laptop: intel and nvidia (GT640M). Usually the nvidia card is not default (i.e. not the first one enumerated by `IDXGIFactory::EnumAdapters`).

In that case, I can still creat a `D3D11Device` using `D3D11CreateDevice` or `D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain`, and set the `pAdapter` to the adapter of the nvidia card. The program runs correctly.

However, when the program terminates, the nvidia card is still doing SOMETHING... I have no idea what it is doing, but it obviously is: the icon is colorful, and the temperature of my laptop raises quickly.

If I set nvidia card as the default for this particular program (which I did in the control panel of nvidia), the problem disappears.

After many experiments, I have drawn the conclusion that the problem occurs if and only if I want to create device with a non-default adapter.

Is this an issue of the nvidia card, or of Direct3D? Is there a solution to it?

Comment: Are you running an "Optimus" system?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I GUESS yes. The intel integrated card is always responsible for the final output, but I want to use the nvidia card to perform all rendering operations.

Comment: [Optimus](http://www.nvidia.com/object/optimus_technology.html) tends to be a bit quirky, so setting your app in the Optimus control panel to use NVIDIA is probably the most robust solution. Generally applications should just use whatever is 'default' and let users configure their system appropriately.